# Query Facebook user's friends through graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement a search bar in an iOS app that searches through a user's friends and displays results. I don't want to have to get all users using https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends and then searching through the results. Is it possible to add a query to such a call (e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?q=TIM)? Using the search function of the graph API seems to only search publicly.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see at the Graph API Explorer, you can't search the list of friends via Graph API,
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends?q=Philip

You can simple get a list with all the friends,
and then in the `for` loop you use to print the results, you can search for a username/or id.

a simple example:

```
FB.api('/me/friends/', function(response) {
    if (response) {
        for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++) {
            var friend = response.data[i];
            if(friend.name === 'Philip') {
                alert('Philip Found!');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using FQL:

```
SELECT uid, username, first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE uid IN
  (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND first_name = 'tim'
```

Although, there’s no explicit wildcard search possible, no LIKE operator supported. But you can fake that using the `strpos` function.

Comment: Is it possible to use FQL in the iOS sdk?

Comment: I don’t know if there is a special method in that SDK for doing FQL queries – but you can always set up FQL queries against the „normal” Graph API endpoint, graph.facebook.com/fql?q=your_query (remember to url-encode it though when passing it as a parameter). See example using the Graph API Explorer, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%2C%20username%2C%20first_name%2C%20last_name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20(SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me())%20AND%20first_name%20%3D%20'tim'